# Wireless WiFi antenna not plugged, despite it being installed

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, kubuntu

So, I got a WiFi USB antenna, and managed to install the drivers both with apt-get and with a Git-hub, I think the problem is not there.

```
sudo apt-get install rtl8812au-dkms
```

I verified that it was installed using the following:

```
sudo dkms status
lsmod | grep 8812
```

wich gave me

rtl8812au, 4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg, 5.3.0-28-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au, 5.6.4.2, 5.3.0-28-generic, x86_64: built

and

8812au               1290240  0
cfg80211              704512  4 iwlmvm,8812au,iwlwifi,mac80211

That makes me think that the drivers are actually installed, but when I plug the antenna nothing happens.
I know similar questions have been asked, but I've found no solution in those questions, sorry if the question is poorly worded or tagged or anything, first time asking.

EDIT1
This is what happens when I run the lsusb command without the device plugged in:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

And now, with the device plugged in:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

EDIT2
SOLVED
Thank you so much guys, it was the wrong driver.
I needed the rtl88x2BU drivers. For Kernel 5.3, I got the working drivers in this GitHub https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lsusb` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: You installed wrong drivers.

Comment: I'l check it right now, thank's for answering.